# CruiseControl with VSS - checks all files

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, visual-sourcesafe

I have cruise control and VSS 6.0. I have configured cruise control every hour with the condition IfModificationExists.

It check for the modification and get the source, but it checks all the files in the VSS. ie my VSS contains 1000 files and only 1 file is modified. CCNet detects 1 modification, but checks for all the files from the VSS with my local. Due to which the script runs every time for a long time.

is thr any option to get only the modified files?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I am running the danger to have many negative votes here, but I am really trying to help on the long run. I have marked my answer "community wiki" so that I prove my intentions are noble.

I don't know the answer to the question you are asking. I am obligated to try and tell you, without wanting to sound dogmatic, that you might consider switching to another version control system. I will not say which, although I can't help saying that I am using Subversion with CruiseControl.NET and it works very nice.

If you go to the "CruiseControl.NET : Visual Source Safe Source Control Block"  [documentation page](http://ccnet.net.henu.edu.cn/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Visual%20Source%20Safe%20Source%20Control%20Block.html) they even have a section at the bottom: Reasons why you might want to consider a different version control system. I guess this means something.